# Why beforeRender() is called two times?

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm Using CakePHP 2.2.0 and I have this AppController:

```
<?php
    App::uses('Controller', 'Controller');

    class AppController extends Controller {
        public function beforeRender(){
           debug('test');
        }
    }
?>
```

and this simple custom controller:

```
<?php

App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');

class ProvidersController extends AppController {

    public function index(){
        debug('index');
    }

}

?>
```

I really do not understand why beforeRender of AppController is called two times... I see two "test" strings in the debug mode, when the URL reachs the index() method of ProvidersController.

Could someone explain it?

Comment: Not sure why, you could trying `debug_print_backtrace()` in the beforeRender to see what is calling it..

Comment: Some suggest that `beforeRender` is fired once for the layout, and once for the `$content_for_layout` (the view); perhaps this is it.

Answer (score 2):

I've seen this behavior when I have a broken src somewhere else in the code. If a javascript file can't be found for example, cake will fire up, causing the logic to run again. This might explain why you are seeing a method like beforeRender() run twice.